# WPF - How to make ItemsControl single item content larger than ItemsControl itself

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

Is it possible to make a datatemplate for ItemsControl, which would 'enlarge' selected item's content beyond ItemsControl height, overlapping other ItemsControl items - but without altering ItemsControl height/width, without shifting adjacent ItemsControl items.
I have interaction triggers and bindings etc, just need UI elements capable of that.
Tried Popup element - but it doesn't look to be the best solution.

EDIT:

Thanks again for your replies, I tried to post a simplier description of my problem - and that was my mistake, sorry. Heres the EXACT problem:
(tried to apply ScaleTransform - it makes my ScrollViewer larger)

```
<s:SurfaceScrollViewer MaxWidth="1920" Margin="50" ClipToBounds="False"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=ScrollViewerYearVisibility}">
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YearItemsSource}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateYearItem}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</s:SurfaceScrollViewer>


<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateYearItem">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Grid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path=CommandDeviceDoubleClick}"/>
        </Grid.InputBindings>

        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="200" Height="200" Stretch="None"
                Source="{Binding Path=ContentImagePathCurrent}">
        </Image>

        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="False"
                    Margin="-248,-210,0,0"
                    Stretch="None"
                    Source="{Binding Path=SlideCurrent.ContentImagePath}">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="3"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Absolutely, [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be your friend here. You don't want to use something like a negative margin since it could still have a negative effect. What are you working in (wpf/sl, or what?) It's probably as easy as just adding a quick storyboard for the selected state in the VSM of the ListBoxItem style template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ScaleGeometry doesnt work - I need to explain more. I have a listbox that shows 200*200 images. On mouse click - I want to replace selected image with another - 300*300 - and that listbox height remains the same - and new 300*300 imege goes beyond lisbox size, and overlaps other items

Comment: Not ScaleGeometry, it's ScaleTransform, and it needs to be a RenderTransform

Comment: Sooo, which are you using, WPF or SL? We can show you how, I just need to know which default template I need to go edit for ya. Piece of cake.

Comment: And - its WPF, Surface SDK

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, you want to keep 2 images in each item. When user clicks an item, the smaller image disappears and the larger item displays larger than the other items and overlaps the other items without effecting the size of other objects in the layout? Also, can multiple be selected at once, or just one at a time? Just trying to visualize the result you're after correctly.

Comment: Mostly like that - smaller image doesnt necessarily have to dissapear - it can stay behind the larger image, which appears on double click. Larger image shows larger than other, going beyond ScrollViewer/ItemsControl top/bottom, overlaping other elements too, by few pixels. ScrollViewer/ItemsControl size and adjacent ItemsControl position shouldnt change. Only one Item can be 'selected'

Comment: Rather than transforms you can also use negative margins.

Comment: No - tried that, but like anything else - it either does enlarge the ItemsControl, or crops the bigger image inside ItemsControl boundaries